# Mathematical proof by induction.

Tags: induction, fibonacci-numbers

How to prove the following using mathematical proof by induction?

$\phi^n = \phi\times F_n + F_{n-1}$

$\phi = 1 + \sqrt 5 /2$

Fn is the Fibonacci number.

I tried solving this using induction but then again I get stuck when solving for the proof of n=k+1.

Thank you